# Add custom action to grid column

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to add a `custom link` much like the `View` link in sales order page. But what I want is when the user click on that `custom link` it will get the value of one of the filter I added then download the necessary template. So basically I have a dropdown that contain the format of the template I want. When I select this and click my `custom link` I want to download or redirect it to my download asset controller. In my .xml file I have this

```
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="entity_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_email">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Email</item>             
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_firstname">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">First Name</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_lastname">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Name</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_middlename">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Middle Name</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
               <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Date</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </column>
   <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">sales/order/view</item>
                <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings<name />
            <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </actionsColumn>

    <!--- I want to add a new action column here for my custom dropdown and my custom link -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your grid listing

```
<actionsColumn name="order_id" class="VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\OrderActions">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</actionsColumn>
```

**VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column**

**OrderActions.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class OrderActions extends Column
{
    private $urlBuilder;

    const ORDER_URL_PATH_EDIT = 'sales/order/view';

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['order_id'])) {
                    $item[$name] = html_entity_decode(
                        '<a target="self" href="' .
                        $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            self::ORDER_URL_PATH_EDIT,
                            [
                                'order_id' => $item['order_id'
                                ],
                            ]
                        )
                        . '">' . $item['order_id'] . '</a>'
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Here i get order id from my custom table in **$item['order_id']**